# How to get an articles revision history from Wikipedia

Tags: rss, wikipedia

I am trying to get revision History from Wikipedia articles so that I can obtain latest changes or events that have happened with reference to that article .

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Syndication mentions about the RSS Feeds that can be obtained wrt to an article by this RSS URL http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ARTICLENAME&action=history&feed=rss .

But the above URL has no parameters as to control the revision history dates. I would like to know if there is any better way to obtain article revision history through a computer program or any way to tweak the given RSS URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) for that. Specifically, [the `revisions` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#revisions_.2F_rv).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Kader_Khan&rvlimit=20&rvdiffto=prev

When executing this URL I will get the diffs for some initial revisions but will fail for later revisions.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal Have a look at https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29223, which talks about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with [pywikipediabot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPywikipediabot), try the snapshot:

```
import wikipedia

site= wikipedia.Site("pt", "wikipedia")

wpage = wikipedia.Page(site, u"Portugal")

for i in wpage.getVersionHistory():
    print i
```